# indexing in lambda function to optimize multiple variables of a sum

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, sympy

I want to solve an optimization problem as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187841/python-optimization-indexed-sum-using-sympy-lambdify-and-scipy/47208090#47208090) thread. Now, I not only want to solve for the `x[1]...x[n]`, but also for the variable y. It looks like something is wrong with the indexing.

```
from sympy import Sum, symbols, Indexed, lambdify
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def _eqn(y, variables, periods, sign=-1.0):
    x, i = symbols("x i")
    n = periods-1
    s = Sum(Indexed('x', i)/(1+0.06)**i, (i, 1, n))
    f = lambdify(x, s, modules=['sympy'])
    return float(sign*(y + f(variables)))

z = 3
results = minimize(lambda xy: _eqn(xy[0], xy[1:z], z),np.zeros(z))
print(results.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is variable number of arguments for minimization then does the following code work for you?

```
from sympy import var
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def _eqn(y, variables, periods, sign=-1.0):    
    f = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(variables):
        f += x/(1+0.06)**(i+1)
    return float(sign*(y + f))

z = 3
results = minimize(lambda xy: _eqn(xy[0], xy[1:z], z),np.zeros(z))
print(results.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems there is an issue in your indexing. The summation runs from 1 to n but by default indexing of list type objects in Python goes from 0 to n-1. If I change this in your code it seems to work. Check it out.

```
import sympy as sp
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

sp.init_printing()

def _eqn(y, variables, periods, sign=-1.0):
    x, i = sp.symbols("x i")
    n = periods-1
    s = sp.Sum(sp.Indexed('x', i)/(1+0.06)**(i+1), (i, 0, n-1)).doit()
    f = sp.lambdify(x, s, modules=['sympy'])
    return float(sign*(y + f(variables)))

z = 3
results = minimize(lambda xy: _eqn(xy[0], xy[1:z], z),np.zeros(z))
print(results.x)
```

Comment: Ok, I see your point. It should be (i+1) though. So in the some I now have x[0] and x[1] as variables. Is your indexing in the minimize function then really correct? Assuming that we change y and variables in the _eqn, wouldn't it be minimize(lambda xy: _eqn(xy[:z-1], xy[z-1], z),np.zeros(z))? Because that the indexing matches the sum variables?! Can I somehow check the result as it deviates in those cases.

Comment: The indexing seems to be correct. Inside the `_eqn` function, `x[0]` and `x[1]` refer to `variables[0]` and `variables[1]` which in turn refer to `xy[1]` and `xy[2]`. You have already separated `xy[0]` into the input argument `y` of the function `_eqn`.

Comment: Ok, I guess I can follow. But why are the result (with i+1) and your first answer different? Does this really have an impact? `x = [var('x'+ str(i)) for i in range(z)]`

Comment: Now I understood. You were talking about (i+1) in the exponent of the denominator. I have updated both my answers. The equation that you are solving has no minimum value for `sign=-1.0` because as we make `y` and `x` larger, the total function become more and more negative. If you set `sign=1.0`, then both the methods give same answer.

Comment: I am sorry but the function you are trying to minimize has a constant Jacobian. Minimization requires solving for Jacobian = 0. So, there is no unique minimum with either `sign=+1.0` or `sign=-1.0`. In that sense both my answers are useless.